# Настроил TM Extra Product Options и WooCommerce не добавляет, почему это может быть?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Всё настроено, пытался настроить и отдельно глобальную форму и добавлять как опцию в картоку товара, как только не делал, но при попытке добавить товар в корзину, отображается только цена и основной товар, а опции не добавляются вообще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перезалил заново в чистый wp тему и всё остальное, всё импортировал и заработало.
Видимо где-то мелкий косяк был, но это уже неважно.